# How do I show the player bar to control the audio in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, background, just-audio

In the project that I am doing, when I run the application in the emulator and go down to the notification area, the buttons to control the audio are not shown.

Can it be modified somehow?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSwes.jpg)

When I run it on android devices it shows correctly, I don't know, if it's just an emulator problem or when it goes to a physical device it works normally

Comment: It's a bit difficult to guess what might be wrong unless you describe what specifically you're doing in the code that might be different from the official example. Does the official example work for you? And if so, what are you doing differently from it?

Comment: I ran the official just_audio_background example and as a result on the lock screen I had the same result, unable to see the play and pause icon. I wonder if it's just because it's on the emulator that you can't see it? https://gyazo.com/3a6f824e4d07ebb889d84dc7446e9df7 See how it looks for android https://gyazo.com/3d91639489b41d98348d3a9c32014dcc